trigger call to external webservice on record change in netsuite
Let's say I want to add, change, or delete a PO line in NetSuite, and I need another system to know when I do that.  How do I go about doing it?
I am using a PO line as an example only, but in theory I am looking for a programming pattern that could be applied to, for instance, item updates, or sales order changes.
I am thinking it has something to do with SuiteScript, and specifically the user events, but I am little unclear on it on HOW to do it.  I am not talking about the communication with the webservice - that is actually the easiest part.  I am talking about what to put into the SuiteScript code.  My current working there is that it will be something like this (this is not perfect JavaScript, treat it more like pseudo-code):
function main ()
{
   return {
      afterSubmit: myAfterSubmit
      beforeSubmit: myBeforeSubmit
   }
}

function myBeforeSubmit(context)
{
    if (context.type == context.UserEventType.DELETE)
    {
        // Talk to other webservice, telling other system to delete record
    }
}

function myAfterSubmit(context)
{
    if (context.type == context.UserEventType.CREATE )
    {
        // Talk to other webservice, telling other system to add record
    }
    else if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.DELETE )
    {
        /* Talk to other webservice, telling other system to update record
         * This will be approve, cancel, reject, pack, ship, and edit, will probably
         * need to ignore some other UserEventType's, or just handle certain event types.
         */
    }
}

Am I at least heading in generally the correct direction.  What especially confuses me from everything I have seen online is the "Delete" event.
This post is quite  close, but doesn't really give more full fledged examples, examples that show the general workflow.  Also, I found  this post, but it discussing using events when other systems are making an external API call to Netsuite.
Since I am new to this. there is obviously more I need to learn, but I just want to know if I am heading in close to the correct direction.  Some of this I got from the documentation here, but this documentation doesn't really address what events can and should be handled in each "submit" function.


Use afterSubmit rather than beforeSubmit.  If you use beforeSubmit, other scripts could change the record before it's committed to the database.
The pattern you're using for your functions looks fine.
The pattern for your overall script does not look correct to me.  NetSuite expects an AMD module as your script and it should have a pattern broadly like the following:

/**
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 *
 */

define(["N/https"], function (https) {

    function beforeLoad(context) {
        ...
    }
    function beforeSubmit(context) {
        ...
    }
    function afterSubmit(context) {
        ...
    }
    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    }
});

Note the mandatory JSDoc tags (@NScriptType and @ApiVersion) at the start of the file, the AMD module inclusion on the first line of the define call, and the return statement which passes the functions from the script as values for keys which match what NetSuite expects from this script type.

Thanks.  Somewhere I read that "DELETE" would not trigger afterSubmit, which is why I did it in beforeSubmit.  Is that not correct?  Maybe I misunderstood what I read in my web searches, especially this post.  The "delete" scenario is the biggest problem I am trying to handle better.  My system needs to know when a PO line, for instance, is deleted.  Also, I guess since I don't need load (this is only to call another webService on changes in NetSuite), I don't need to define beforeLoad, correct?

What you've read about DELETE not triggering afterSubmit appears to be inaccurate - I just tested it and a log in afterSubmit was generated during a sales order deletion.  Eric is generally correct about anything SuiteScript, so I'm guessing this is something that has changed some time in the 5+ years since that was posted.  You can easily test for yourself just by adding a log to both beforeSubmit and afterSubmit and check that they are both logged when you delete a record.  Doing both insures against any other issues which might prevent the script running.

That said, point 1 in my answer doesn't really apply to DELETE events; the record is being deleted, so changes by any other scripts are not going to matter.  Another point: deleting a PO line will not trigger a DELETE event.  That would be an EDIT.  DELETE is only triggered when deleting the entire record.  You could use a User Event script and compare lines to detect this, or you could use a line based client script function (EG: validateLine) to make your changes.  If you do this, consider using promise versions of the APIs to keep performance reasonable.
